# How to output SQLAlchemy logger only to a file

Tags: python, logging, sqlalchemy

From what I read in the SQLAlchemy logging configuration documentation, I understood that the echo argument on `sqlalchemy.create_engine` controls whether sqlalchemy logging is forced to stdout, but shouldn't affect whether log messages are available to log handlers.

In the code below, I get no output to stdout OR db.log if `echo=False` and I get output to both stdout AND db.log if `echo=True`.   I want nothing to stdout while db.log is still populated.   How can I accomplish that?

This is python 2.7.6 and sqlalchemy 0.9.9

```
import sqlalchemy
import logging

active_db_url = 'postgres://user:pass@localhost/log_test'

db_log_file_name = 'db.log'
db_log_level = logging.INFO

db_handler = logging.FileHandler(db_log_file_name)
db_handler.setLevel(db_log_level)

db_logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy')
db_logger.addHandler(db_handler)

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(active_db_url, echo=True)
engine.connect()
```

** EDIT SOLVED**
db_logger requires its logLevel be set, too.  Not just db_handler.

```
import sqlalchemy
import logging

active_db_url = 'postgres://user:pass@localhost/log_test'

db_log_file_name = 'db.log'
db_handler_log_level = logging.INFO
db_logger_log_level = logging.DEBUG

db_handler = logging.FileHandler(db_log_file_name)
db_handler.setLevel(db_handler_log_level)

db_logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy')
db_logger.addHandler(db_handler)
db_logger.setLevel(db_logger_log_level)

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(active_db_url, echo=False)
engine.connect()
```

Comment: I think I've figured it out.  Logger requires a logLevel, too.  See edit above.

Comment: As I was typing this, it was confirmed.  Solved on the SQLAlchemy mailing list by Michael Bayer.   https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/i699GUgxouo

Comment: Setting the logLevel alone is fine: db_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO). The handler is just to process(write) the message.

Answer (score 5):

First create a file handle to write logs.

```
handler = logging.FileHandler('app.log')
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Get sqlalchemy logger and add this handle.

```
logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy').addHandler(handler)
```